# como puedo filtrar por selector?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy intentando filtrar a través de un selector de ciudades, quiero seleccionar la ciudad deseada en el selector para que me devuelva las clínicas que contienen esa provincia, algo se me escapa porque no obtengo el resultado deseado.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { getClinic } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import {Clinic} from '@icofcv/common';
import { selectClinics } from '../../actions/detailClinics'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

export const SearchFilterClinics = () => {

const [clinicList, setClinicList] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
const [clinicListFilteredSelect, setClinicListFilteredSelect] = useState<Clinic[>([]);
  
const [filterSelectClinic, setFilterSelectClinic] = useState("");
    
console.log(filterSelectClinic);
    
const fetchClinicList = async () => {
     getClinic().then((response)=>{
         console.log(response)
         setClinicList(response);
         setClinicListFilteredSelect(response)
     }).catch ( (error)  => {
         console.error(error);
         throw error;
     });
}


////filter

const handleChangeSelect = e =>{
     setFilterSelectClinic(e.target.value);
     filterSelect(e.target.value);
}

const filterSelect=(termSearch)=>{
     const resultFilterSelect = clinicList.filter((element) => {
          if(element.province?.toString().toLowerCase().includes(termSearch.toLowerCase() )
          ){
            return element;
          }
        });
        setClinicListFilteredSelect(resultFilterSelect);
      }

      useEffect (() => {
        fetchClinicList();  
    }, []);

    return  (
                <>
                   <div>

                                <Form.Label htmlFor="text">Provincia</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Select aria-label="provincias"  onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>
                                        <option data-postal="00" value="todos">Todos</option>
                                        <option data-postal="01" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Alava/Araba</option>
                                        <option data-postal="02" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Albacete</option>
                                        <option data-postal="03" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Alicante</option>
                                        <option data-postal="04" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Almería</option>
                                        <option data-postal="05" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Avila</option>
                                        <option data-postal="06" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Badajoz</option>
                                        <option data-postal="07" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Islas Baleares</option>
                                        <option data-postal="08" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Barcelona</option>
                                        <option data-postal="09" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Burgos</option>
                                        <option data-postal="10" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Cáceres</option>
                                        <option data-postal="11" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Cádiz</option>
                                        <option data-postal="12" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Castellón</option>
                                        <option data-postal="13" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Ciudad Real</option>
                                        <option data-postal="14" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Córdoba</option>
                                        <option data-postal="15" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>A Coruña/La Coruña</option>
                                        <option data-postal="16" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Cuenca</option>
                                        <option data-postal="17" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Gerona/Girona</option>
                                        <option data-postal="18" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Granada</option>
                                        <option data-postal="19" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Guadalajara</option>
                                        <option data-postal="20" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Gipuzkoa/Guipuzcoa</option>
                                        <option data-postal="21" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Huelva</option>
                                        <option data-postal="22" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Huesca</option>
                                        <option data-postal="23" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Jaen</option>
                                        <option data-postal="24" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>León</option>
                                        <option data-postal="25" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Lérida/Lleida</option>
                                        <option data-postal="26" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>La Rioja</option>
                                        <option data-postal="27" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Lugo</option>
                                        <option data-postal="28" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Madrid</option>
                                        <option data-postal="29" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Málaga</option>
                                        <option data-postal="30" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Murcia</option>
                                        <option data-postal="31" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Navarra</option>
                                        <option data-postal="32" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Orense/Ourense</option>
                                        <option data-postal="33" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Asturias</option>
                                        <option data-postal="34" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Palencia</option>
                                        <option data-postal="35" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Las Palmas</option>
                                        <option data-postal="36" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Pontevedra</option>
                                        <option data-postal="37" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Salamanca</option>
                                        <option data-postal="38" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>S.C.Tenerife</option>
                                        <option data-postal="39" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Cantabria</option>
                                        <option data-postal="40" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Segovia</option>
                                        <option data-postal="41" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Sevilla</option>
                                        <option data-postal="42" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Soria</option>
                                        <option data-postal="43" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Tarragona</option>
                                        <option data-postal="44" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Teruel</option>
                                        <option data-postal="45" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Toledo</option>
                                        <option data-postal="46" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Valencia</option>
                                        <option data-postal="47" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Valladolid</option>
                                        <option data-postal="48" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Bizkaia/Vizcaya</option>
                                        <option data-postal="49" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Zamora</option>
                                        <option data-postal="50" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Zaragoza</option>
                                        <option data-postal="51" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Ceuta</option>
                                        <option data-postal="52" value={filterSelectClinic} onChange={ handleChangeSelect}>Melilla</option>
                                         
                                   
                                </Form.Select>

                                <div>RESULT</div>
                                {
                                    clinicListFilteredSelect.map((clinic) => (
                                        <div>
                                            <div>{clinic.title}</div>
                                            <div>{clinic.propsPhone}</div>
                                            <div>{clinic.mobile}</div>
                                            <div>{clinic.email}</div>
                                            <div>{clinic.province} </div>
                                            <div>{clinic.registry}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </div>

                          
                </>
            )
}
```

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de como funciona ese select. Pero a primera vista el fallo es que le pones a todos los elementos del select el mismo value. Así nunca cambia el valor, siempre es el mismo. Deberías de poner el nombre de cada provincia en el value también.

Comment: Además, debes poner un if en la función filterSelect, para evitar aplicar filter cuando se selecciona la opción Todos